# JAVA, list of lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have list and list of lists:

```
ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I do not understand the behavior of these lists. I decided to show you a simple example:

```
listOfLists.clear();

singleList.clear();
singleList.add("A");
singleList.add("B");
singleList.add("C");
listOfLists.add(singleList);

singleList.clear();
singleList.add("D");
singleList.add("E");
singleList.add("F");
listOfLists.add(singleList);

singleList.clear();
singleList.add("G");
singleList.add("H");
singleList.add("I");
listOfLists.add(singleList);

for(int x = 0; x < listOfLists.size(); x++)
{
    for(int z = 0; z < singleList.size(); z++)
        {
        System.out.print(listOfLists.get(x).get(z));
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

And the result I got was:

G H I 
G H I 
G H I

Instead:

A B C
D E F
G H I

Where is a problem with my thinking? What should I do to get result as above?

Comment: Because when you add singleList to listOfLists you **do not make a copy of it**, you add a **reference** to first list inside second one (so you won't even duplicate its content).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Objects are *always* passed as references in Java.

When you add `singleList` to `listOfLists`, you are in fact adding **a reference** to `singleList`. Since you've added it 3 times, you got the current value of `singleList`, repeated 3 times.

The *"previous values"* of `singleList` are stored nowhere, so `A B C` and `D E F` are lost.

You need to make a copy of your list, by using `new ArrayList<String>(singleList)`. Then, add this copy to `listOfLists`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Also now I understand what was wrong with my thinking.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is how object references work. Going step by step

```
singleList.clear();
singleList.add("A");
singleList.add("B");
singleList.add("C");
listOfLists.add(singleList);

//singleList -> A, B, C 
//listOfLists -> singleList

singleList.clear();
singleList.add("D");
singleList.add("E");
singleList.add("F");
listOfLists.add(singleList);

//singleList -> D, E, F
//listOfLists -> singleList, singleList

singleList.clear();
singleList.add("G");
singleList.add("H");
singleList.add("I");
listOfLists.add(singleList);

//singleList -> G, H, I
//listOfLists -> singleList, singleList, singleList
```

Now, you are printing listOfLists, wich contains 3 times singleList. But singleList contains now G, H, I

To get the desired result, you need to use different lists, one with A, B, C, other with D, E, F, and another one with G, H, I.

```
singleList1 -> A, B, C
singleList2 -> D, E, F
singleList3 -> F, G, H
listOfLists -> singleList1, singleList2, singleList3
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having different variables for singleList, you can also do this when adding to listOfLists:
listOfLists.add(new ArrayList(singleList));

this creates a copy of singlelist that has a different memory location unlike the one you did which refers to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

To make a list of lists, you can easily use `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>;` to make a list of lists of integers, or replaces `Integer` with `String` or whatever you want. To access items, use `listOfLists.get(0).get(0)` for example, to get the first item of the first list inside of `listOfLists`. Not sure if this helps.